# How to handle feature requests that add new package dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

I am the maintainer of a package on hackage, [lrucache](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lrucache).  I recently received a feature request for adding instances for `Binary` and `NFData`.  Both of those are useful things to have, and I have no issue with those instances, in principle.

However, both of them introduce new package dependencies, and I want to keep my package's dependency list as minimal as possible.  Is there a sane way to handle this?  There are probably well over twenty different packages that provide useful type classes the data structures in `lrucache` could implement, and get some benefit from.

Obviously, adding all of them as dependencies is a non-starter.  But what else can be done?

I can add flags to lrucache.cabal that will enable compiling various instances.  That works, in terms of making the dependency list minimal, except when you want it.  But it's horrible in the real world, because you can't specify build flags in build-depends sections.  So you can depend on a package with a particular flag, but not specify that dependency.  This quickly reduces to near-uselessness.

I can create a bunch of orphan instance packages.  This has the advantage of allowing dependencies on those instances to be specified in a build-depends section.  Its main disadvantage is adding a ton of extra packages to hackage, and needing to maintain them as separate packages.

What else can I do?  What's the right thing to do?

Comment: The "orphan instances package" approach seems to be a common strategy, at least. The right thing to do is probably invent better dependency management, but...

Comment: @C. A. McCann, I personally dislike it when software uses `./configure --enable-Z`. I like things simple -- having a package marked installed means it's installed, not "it's installed with options X and Y but not Z". Perhaps Hackage could _organize_ orphan instances packages better, but I don't think they're illegitimate in concept.

Comment: @gatoatigrado: I agree. Cabal organizing them better would also qualify as "better dependency management" as I mentioned, so feel free to invent it. :] I'm not sure what the obstacles to implementing a system like that would be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043442/where-do-quickcheck-instances-belong-in-a-cabal-package/ ?

Comment: `nfdata` can have the instance in the main package -- its a dependency for plenty of core packages already. `binary` *used* to be the only go-to serialization package, but there are a few competitors now. For that, a separate package could be okay, but if the serialization code is straightforward enough, you could just provide it in docs/a wiki page, and let users write their own instance or serialization code when necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Short of an optional dependencies system in cabal (the packaging system) itself, the options aren't too good.

One option is as follows. You can create an additional package of your own for each additional package that you may want your main package to integrate with.

For example, if you would like `lrucache` to integrate with `binary`, you could make an additional package `lrucache-binary` containing the integration (in this case, type class instances). Likewise, a new package of your own `lrucache-nfdata` to integrate `lrucache` with `nfdata`.

Then if someone would like both `lrucache` and its integration with `binary`, he can depend on `[binary, lrucache, lrucache-binary]` together.

Comment: That's exactly what the "orphan instance packages" thing I mentioned is, I think.

Answer (score 3):

What if you just maintain two packages: `lrucache`, which depends on a zillion different things, and then `lrucache-lite` (or `lrucache-minimal`) which is more or less what you have now. Then if people want to minimize their dependencies, they use the lite version, and if they don't care about having a zillion dependencies, they use the standard version. The big one would probably depend on the lite one, to avoid code duplication.

Comment: I've seen this with the names `lrucache` and `lrucache-instances`.  That way there are only two packages, but there's no ability to pick and choose instances.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the game, but my two cents:

1. A libraries public API (which includes class instances) should never change based on build flags or package availability - it is punishing for down-stream devs and distro package maintainers.
2. I'll add a dependency without question to anything in the Haskell Platform (except maybe 'unix' or 'win32' or the like).

That still leaves 'binary', however according to its Hackage page it is available in multiple Linux distributions, and in my experience installs cleanly on Windows. In this case I would accept a patch, but not author it myself.

This doesn't really answer the question straight out, but hopefully illustrates the thought process I would use.

Answer (score 0):

> I can add flags to lrucache.cabal that will enable compiling various
>   instances. That works, in terms of making the dependency list minimal,
>   except when you want it. But it's horrible in the real world, because
>   you can't specify build flags in build-depends sections. So you can
>   depend on a package with a particular flag, but not specify that
>   dependency. This quickly reduces to near-uselessness.

This might be exactly what you say doesn't work for you above, but can you include your imports and class definitions in [conditionally-compiled](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-latest/doc/users-guide/#conditional-compilation) CPP pragmas? I suppose wrapped around `imports` of internal modules which in turn import one of your "optional dependencies".

I haven't tried this, but am very interested in knowing the answer as well.

Comment: Yes, that works.  But lets say that I did it, for instance, for a Binary instance.  Let's say you're writing a program that uses lrucache, and wants to use the Binary instance to serialize it.  There would be no way to indicate that in the build-depends section of your cabal file.  That's the problem with that approach.