# How do I make the partially-applied function type into a functor?

Tags: haskell, types

There is an example program in [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids):

```
instance Functor ((->) a) where
    fmap = (.)
```

While I have trouble compiling it:

> Duplicate instance declarations:
>
> instance Functor ((->) a) -- Defined at partiallyApplied.hs:6:10
>
> instance Functor ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’

As [How do you override Haskell type class instances provided by package code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643360/how-do-you-override-haskell-type-class-instances-provided-by-package-code) mention, I should define a new type for the declaration of `Functor`. I try so but fail:

```
newtype Ntype a = N ((->) a)

instance Functor ((->) a) where
    fmap = (.)
```

> • Expecting one more argument to ‘(->) a’
>
> Expected a type, but ‘(->) a’ has kind ‘* -> *’
>
> • In the type ‘(->) a’
>
> In the definition of data constructor ‘N’
>
> In the newtype declaration for ‘NewType’

How do I make it works?

Comment: `newtype Ntype a b = N (a -> b)` then `instance Functor (Ntype a) where ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3072788/alec):

```
newtype Ntype a b = N (a -> b)

instance Functor (Ntype a) where
    fmap f (N g) = N (f . g)
```

Thanks [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3072788/alec)!